# Repeater inside other control

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I'm using Telerik's AJAX controls, and I have a slight issue. In my application the user enters the number of 'weeks', and then the program dynamically adds RadPane's to a repeater (with a splitter so they can modify the size), with RadGrid's inside the panes.

I have the following markup:

```
<telerik:RadSplitter ID="splt" runat="server" Width="100%">              
<asp:Repeater ID="rptSplitter" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptSplitter_ItemDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>
<telerik:RadPane ID="pane" runat="server">
<asp:Label ID="lblText" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"From") %>'></asp:Label>
<telerik:RadGrid ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<MasterTableView runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID">
<Columns>
<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ConsignmentNo" HeaderText="Consignment" SortExpression="ConsignmentNo">
</telerik:GridBoundColumn>
<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Customer" HeaderText="Customer" SortExpression="Customer"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
</Columns>
</MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
</telerik:RadPane>
</ItemTemplate>
<SeparatorTemplate>
<telerik:RadSplitBar runat="server"></telerik:RadSplitBar>
</SeparatorTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</telerik:RadSplitter>
```

When binding the repeater however, I get the following exception (well, the exception doesn't display, but I can 'see' it in the itemdatabound event of the grid):

> "RadPane must be placed inside a RadSplitter control."

Any ideas on how I can somehow get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you could get around this by putting everything inside the repeater control into a usercontrol instead.  Ditch the repeater control, then loop through your collection, dynamically adding the panes with the usercontrols in them.

Telerik has a [demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/splitter/examples/dynamicobjectcreation/defaultcs.aspx) of dynamically adding panes to a splitter.